# Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: windows, security, sql-server-2005, connection, log-shipping

I'm trying to connect between two SQL Servers to set up log-shipping.

I'm getting the following error when connecting from the Publisher to the Subscriber:

Cannot connect to DRBOX

Additional information: Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server).

I can connect ok from the Subscriber to the Publisher.

Publisher is 2 node active passive cluster, Windows 2003 R2 Enterprise x64 SP2, SQL2005 Enterprise SP3
Subscriber is stand alone, Windows 2003 Standard x32 SP1, SQL 2005 Enterprise SP3

Answer (score 1):

When I have seen this error it has been Kerberos-related as the server OS has to be configured to allow Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to access the Subscriber by changing its dedicated service account (housing the SQL services) to local system.

I'd prefer to use the dedicated service account - so if anyone knows why this is happening please shout.

***This is now a problem again, I can't use the local system account for logshipping as it doesn't have permissions to see the Subscriber***

Have tried using SETSPN.EXE to register the Servers SPN - but this hasn't seemed to work.